# ffmpeg colormatrix operations only for 8bpc?

Tags: ffmpeg, prores, colorspace

Unless I'm bad at reading, this page states that colormatrix is only good for 8 bpc.

From [Colorspace support in FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/colorspace):

> ... colormatrix produces horrible quality for anything > 8bpc (8-bit per component)

Backstory.  One of my typical workflows is to convert 16bit tiffs and 10bit DPX frames into 10bit prores.  However, I think the input colorspace of the frames is assumed to be bt601 and I would always get encodes that looks just slightly off from my originals.  I solved this by adding:

`-vf colormatrix=bt601:bt709`

And it looks fine visually.  The difference between the source and encode I always just assumed was the lossy compression.

So can someone chime in on if the `colormatrix=bt601:bt709` operation is 'supposed' to be bad when the source and encode are >10bpc?  Or is the info on that page outdated?  Or should I be doing it a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as it says a couple of lines above, `colormatrix supports only 8bpc (8-bit per component) pixel formats`. So, when a 16-bit input is filtered with colormatrix, it will be converted to 8-bits. And won't get converted back to 16-bit unless manually done or auto-converted due to output encoder limitations. But that's pointless anyway, as the precision has been lost.

Use the colorspace filter.

```
-vf colorspace=all=bt709:range=tv:format=yuv422p10:iall=bt601:irange=tv
```

Depending on your use case, format may need to be `yuv444p10`. Depending in your input, irange may need to be `pc`.

Comment: Sorry, it's `bt601-6-525` for NTSC or `bt601-6-625` for PAL.

Comment: Yep I'm noticing `colormatrix` vs `colorspace` in 10bit encodes.  The `colormatrix` conversions all look noisier in gradients.  It's not hugely perceptible to the naked eye but I can see it while boosting/enhancing a still frame.  But the other detriment is that the added noise of `colormatrix` was making the prores file bigger by roughly 35% for even less quality.